# How can this proc execute work without quoting passed parameter value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can this code work? I've never found using text without delimiting with single quotes to work, but this does and should not. Maybe I've found a bug in SQL Server. If so, do I get a medal?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Trevor
-- Create date: 20/10/2023
-- Description: Parameter Test
-- =============================================
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE spParameterTest
     @a INT
    ,@b VARCHAR(50)
    ,@c DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
         @a AS a
        ,@b AS b
        ,@c AS c
END
GO
```

and

```
EXEC spParameterTest
     @a = 1
    ,@b = Trevor
    ,@c = '2023/10/20'
```

Gives unexpected results, as

```
a|b|c
1|Trevor|2023-10-20

(1 row affected)
```

Expected results

```
EXEC spParameterTest
     @a = 1
    ,@b = 0Trevor
    ,@c = '2023/10/20'
```

causes this

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'Trevor'.
```

but this

```
EXEC spParameterTest
     @a = 1
    ,@b = '0Trevor'
    ,@c = '2023/10/20'
```

gives

```
a|b|c
1|0Trevor|2023-10-20

(1 row affected)
```

as expected.

Comment: Sql Server silently converts "id literals" and quoted literals to strings in procedure parameters, so it "just works". 0Trevor is not a valid id literal though

Comment: `Trevor` is a quirk that's highly unlikely to appear in actual use-  when applications call a stored procedure they'll pass actual parameter values, they won't construct a `exec ...` string. SQL scripts are far more likely to pass variables than raw strings. I'd be more concerned with the localized string `'2023/10/20'` instead of the unambiguous `2023-10-20` or `20231020` or an actual `date` variable

Comment: BTW that's quite an unexpected quirk I've never encountered before.

Comment: Maybe 0Trevor is considered as an identifier?! while others like integers, decimals, and strings are considered strings?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server parses the unquoted string as an identifier and, if valid, uses the value as the procedure parameter value. This can be observed as follows:

```
EXEC spParameterTest
     @a = 1
    ,@b = StringOf128Charactersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ,@c = '2023-10-20';
```

The above results in successful proc execution with the value truncated to 50 characters.

Passing a longer value:

```
EXEC spParameterTest
     @a = 1
    ,@b = StringOf129Charactersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ,@c = '2023-10-20';
```

results in the error below. Note the word "identifier" in the error message.

> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 233 The identifier that starts with
> 'StringOf129Charactersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Comment: Interesting that it is parsed as an identifier. I guess this is because use case for the feature was for using with things like `sp_help`

Comment: @MartinSmith, I parsed the script with the `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom` parser and the respective parameters values are types `IntegerLiteral`, `IdentifierLiteral`, and `StringLiteral`. Not sure what other use cases there might be for `IdentifierLiteral` in the T-SQL world.

Comment: Following that explanation,
1. Should the parsing behave like that?
2. If a valid identifier is found, does it matter?
3. Should Microsoft fix this and make the parser behave as expected? (no quotes, complain)

Comment: @TrevorMcComb ,the behavior where a literal that is not a [constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is parsed as an identifier dates back to SQL 2000, if not earlier. I can see this behavior as appropriate for function parameters (which may refer to column names) but I can't think of a use-case for `EXECUTE` statement parameters.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the identifier exists or not from a parsing perspective. As long as the identifier name conforms to [rules for regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16#rules-for-regular-identifiers), the value can be treated as a string constant at execute time. I would personally prefer an error but MS likes to avoid breaking changes.